# Connecting to Windows Postgresql takes 10 seconds

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I installed Postgresql 9.6 on Windows (x64), using the default installer.

I did this on 2 almost identical machines. On the first machine making a connection to localhost (for example by using `psql`) is instant, while on the other machine it takes more than 10 seconds.

I even copied the entire directory of the first machine, to make sure there is no difference, but the problem persists. The services are the same, and already running when Windows starts.

What on earth could cause this delay on that one machine?
Any way to identify what's going on?

Comment: Maybe DNS lookup? What happens when you use the IP address instead the server _name_?

Comment: That's it ! Thank you. Now I have to find out why DNS to even localhost is that slow, but at least I know it has nothing to do with Postgresql.